# Getting values from an XML file into an array

Tags: java, android, xml

In my app I use an array of drawable ids.
It's an XML file saved at res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/home</item>
        <item>@drawable/settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/logout</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Then I retrive it using this code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0);
```

But I get an error saying: **array** "cannot be resolved or is not a field".

So How do I get an array of ints that contains the ids from the xml file?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was ok. In my res dir there was an image with a capital letter in it's name! and that's Invalid file name which must contain only [a-z0-9_.] :) So that's why there was an error in the R class. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your project. Project - Clean... And check your imports. Do CTRL + Shift + O

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [typed array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) in arrays.xml file within your res folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/home</item>
        <item>@drawable/settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/logout</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Then in your activity access them like so:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
//get resourceid by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)
// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

im wondering maybe should you have it declared in res/values/strings.xml like

```
<string-array name="numbers_array">
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
```

and then sunstitute your ids for the numbers in the array above...